# passing razor value into angular controller

Tags: angularjs, razor

I've looked at a half dozen examples, but none of them seems to work for me - maybe because of the peculiar **var myController = []** format of the code I inherited.

**.cshtml:**

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app="cmorApp">
    <div 
         data-ng-controller="myCtrl" 
         data-ng-init="referralId =  @Model.ReferralId">
         ...
```

This works, inasmuch as my page correctly renders the value I seek:

> data-ng-init="referralId = 12345"

Now I'm just trying to capture it in my controller.

**Controller:**

```
var myCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', 'FileUploader',
    function ($scope, $http, FileUploader, referralId) {

        console.log(referralId);

        //$scope.init = function (referralId) {
        //    console.log(referralId);
        //}
        //$scope.init();
```

It outputs **undefined**.
What am I missing?

.

**UPDATE:**

This *sort of* works:

```
ng-init="init(@Model.ReferralId)
```

.

```
    $scope.init = function (referralId) {
        $scope.referralId = referralId;
    }
```

The problem is, the value is not there when I need it. It only there if I let the page do some processing.

I can't do this, or I'm back to undefined:

```
    $scope.init = function (referralId) {
        $scope.referralId = referralId;
    }
    console.log($scope.referralId);
```

Comment: Controller runs before view gets compiled. Would need to use a watch if you need that value in controller. Seems like bad app design

Comment: This is done all over the place - common practice. Just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: far more common practice to separate concerns. Passing data to view to read it into controller is backwards thinking since controller has to run first to create scope for the view to get compiled with

Comment: Suggestions? When I search for 'pass MVC Razor value to angular controller', these are the only solutions I find.

Comment: did you try a watch? And why not do most common approach and request data from server from inside angular app?

Comment: see console in this demo with a watch http://plnkr.co/edit/e7TKQCckm3ym2QSiyzl7?p=preview